# Ignoring null values in in a postgresql rank() window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing a SQL query using PostgreSQL that needs to rank people that "arrive" at some location. Not everyone arrives however. I am using a `rank()` window function to generate arrival ranks, but in the places where the arrival time is null, rather than returning a null rank, the `rank()` aggregate function just treats them as if they arrived after everyone else. What I want to happen is that these no-shows get a rank of `NULL` instead of this imputed rank.

Here is an example. Suppose I have a table `dinner_show_up` that looks like this:

```
 | Person | arrival_time | Restaurant |
 +--------+--------------+------------+
 | Dave   |     7        | in_and_out |
 | Mike   |     2        | in_and_out | 
 | Bob    |   NULL       | in_and_out |
```

Bob never shows up. The query I'm writing would be:

```
select Person, 
       rank() over (partition by Restaurant order by arrival_time asc) 
               as arrival_rank
from dinner_show_up;
```

And the result will be

```
 | Person | arrival_rank | 
 +--------+--------------+
 | Dave   |     2        | 
 | Mike   |     1        | 
 | Bob    |     3        |
```

What I want to happen instead is this:

```
 | Person | arrival_rank | 
 +--------+--------------+
 | Dave   |     2        | 
 | Mike   |     1        | 
 | Bob    |     NULL     |
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement around the `rank()`:

```
select Person, 
       (case when arrival_time is not null
             then rank() over (partition by Restaurant order by arrival_time asc) 
        end) as arrival_rank
from dinner_show_up;
```

Comment: +1 Interestingly, in SQL Server rank will process nulls before not nulls and rank will have gap, looks like postgres processing nulls after not nulls or don't count them at all?

Comment: @RomanPekar You can define whether or not you want NULLs first or last in the ORDER BY of the RANK() function (or regular queries of course) -> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html

Answer (score 14):

A more general solution for all aggregate functions, not only rank(), is to partition by 'arrival_time is not null' in the over() clause. That will cause all null arrival_time rows to be placed into the same group and given the same rank, leaving the non-null rows to be ranked relative only to each other.

For the sake of a meaningful example, I mocked up a CTE having more rows than the intial problem set. Please forgive the wide rows, but I think they better contrast the differing techniques.

```
with dinner_show_up("person", "arrival_time", "restaurant") as (values
   ('Dave' ,    7, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Mike' ,    2, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Bob'  , null, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Peter',    3, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Jane' , null, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Merry',    5, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Sam'  ,    5, 'in_and_out')
  ,('Pip'  ,    9, 'in_and_out')
)

select 
   person
  ,case when arrival_time is not null then         rank() over (                                      order by arrival_time) end as arrival_rank_without_partition
  ,case when arrival_time is not null then         rank() over (partition by arrival_time is not null order by arrival_time) end as arrival_rank_with_partition
  ,case when arrival_time is not null then percent_rank() over (                                      order by arrival_time) end as arrival_pctrank_without_partition
  ,case when arrival_time is not null then percent_rank() over (partition by arrival_time is not null order by arrival_time) end as arrival_pctrank_with_partition
from dinner_show_up
```

This query gives the same results for arrival_rank_with/without_partition. However, the results for percent_rank() do differ: without_partition is wrong, ranging from 0% to 71.4%, whereas with_partition correctly gives pctrank() ranging from 0% to 100%.

This same pattern applies to the ntile() aggregate function, as well.

It works by separating all null values from non-null values for purposes of the ranking. This ensures that Jane and Bob are excluded from the percentile ranking of 0% to 100%.

```
 |person|arrival_rank_without_partition|arrival_rank_with_partition|arrival_pctrank_without_partition|arrival_pctrank_with_partition|
 +------+------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
 |Jane  |null                          |null                       |null                             |null                          |
 |Bob   |null                          |null                       |null                             |null                          |
 |Mike  |1                             |1                          |0                                |0                             |
 |Peter |2                             |2                          |0.14                             |0.2                           |
 |Sam   |3                             |3                          |0.28                             |0.4                           |
 |Merry |4                             |4                          |0.28                             |0.4                           |
 |Dave  |5                             |5                          |0.57                             |0.8                           |
 |Pip   |6                             |6                          |0.71                             |1.0                           |
```

Comment: Very good and detailed answer.  Especially like the inclusion of how to get the percent rank correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select Person, 
   rank() over (partition by Restaurant order by arrival_time asc) 
           as arrival_rank
from dinner_show_up
where arrival_time is not null
union 
select Person,NULL as arrival_rank
from dinner_show_up
where arrival_time is null;
```

Comment: First - you need to change `union` or `union all`. Otherwise postgres will waste alot of time on serching for duplicates. Secong - this query involves 2 table scans - it will still be ineficient.